# How do I create custom authorization rules to a particular action in a controller in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a User model, but I would like another model (`Client`) to have unique authorization access to a particular action of another controller.

I do not want the Client model to access an action in the `Client` controller. I want the `Client` model to access the `compare` action of the `stages` controller.

How do I do that ?

Edit1: I should have specified. I have devise & decl_auth already installed. But devise & decl_auth are managing my `Users`. I need to have more authorization rules for another model outside of the `Users` model.

Comment: You may want to consider reducing all your various models into one "User" model, and then define roles, like client, as an attribute of that model. This will make role based authorization much, much easier, especially with CanCan that Srdjan recommended below.

Comment: Zachary, I actually have that implemented. The problem with roles, is that I need to have my Users model `has_many` Clients. If a user role is a client, I can't do `Users` has_many `Users`.

Comment: Of course you can @marcamillion ! It's not the right place to answer that, but you can. You could think about a `user_relations` table with columns (parent_id, child_id, type)

Answer (score 1):

If you set up CanCan, this should be a fairly easy thing to do. Here's a link to the RailsCast showing how something like this can be done, http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan.

Extensive docs are here: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki

Comment: I should have specified. I have devise & decl_auth already installed. But devise & decl_auth are managing my `Users`. I need to have more authorization rules for another model outside of the Users model.

Comment: I use cancan and roles to manage access for varying types of users to every controller/model in my app. Admins can access everything, Managers a subset, Employees a smaller subset, etc.

I'm not sure if declarative_authorization will allow you the same granularity, but having Users with roles as opposed to User subtypes would make things easier, IMO.